# How to add to classpath of running PySpark session

Tags: pyspark, jar, pmml

I have a PySpark notebook running in AWS EMR. In my specific case, I want to use `pyspark2pmml` to create `pmml` for a model I just trained. However, I get the following error (when running `pyspark2pmml.PMMLBuilder` but I don't think that matters).

```
JPMML-SparkML not found on classpath
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/1623111492721-0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark2pmml/__init__.py", line 14, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError("JPMML-SparkML not found on classpath")
RuntimeError: JPMML-SparkML not found on classpath
```

I know that this is caused by my Spark session not have reference to the needed class. What I don't know is how to start a Spark session with that class available. I found one other answer using `%%conf -f`, but that changed other settings which in turn kept me from using `sc.install_pypi_package`, which I also needed.

Is there a way that I could have started the Spark session with that JPMML class available, but without changing any other settings?

Answer (score 0):

So, here's **an** answer, but not the one I want.

To add that class to the classpath I can start my work with this:

```
%%configure -f
{
    "jars": [
        "{some_path_to_s3}/jpmml-sparkml-executable-1.5.13.jar"
    ]
}
```

That creates the issue I referenced above, where I don't have the ability to `sc.install_pypi_package`. However, I can add that package in a more manual way. First step was to create a zip file of just the needed modules using the zip from the project's github (in this case, just the `pyspark2pmml` directory, instead of the whole zip). Then that module can be added using `sc.addPyFile`

```
sc.addPyFile('{some_path_to_s3}/pyspark2pmml.zip')
```

After this, I can run the original commands exactly as I expected.